# Is there a difference in rendering between Paperwhite and Voyage?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

The question title pretty much sums it up.  If I'm testing how my eBook looks across different devices, and I have a Paperwhite for testing, is there a significant difference between that and the Voyage, such that I should buy a Voyage for testing as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the Voyage rendering system is *similar* to the Paperwhite, but not the same.

I (currently) know of one difference between the two; there is a rendering bug in the Voyage that the Paperwhite does not have, as described on the [MobileRead forums](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showpost.php?p=3130364&postcount=58):

> let's not forget that Voyage has that weirdo width bug, too, for
>   images? Not the same, mind you...but not totally dissimilar, either.
>   If you have an image that's <50% wide in Voyage, you're set; but if
>   it's 51%, you're screwed, it blows up to full width. Now, again: this
>   isn't the same as this wacky, "the image won't float unless it's SMALL
>   enough, in iOS," but...I wonder if they are in some wild-ass way
>   related? In some algo, somewhere?
>
> —Hitch

I'll try to update this with any further information I get.